# How to update/edit record in CoreData using swift 3?

Tags: core-data, swift3, uistepper

How to update/edit record in CoreData using swift 3 ? I have a tableview and in every cell I have stepper, now I can get the stepper value but I don't know how to update/edit the old value in the CoreData.

I found this function but its not working with swift 3

```
func saveLoginData(accessToken: String, userName: String) {
    var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "LoginData")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "userName = %@", userName)

    if let fetchResults = appDel.managedObjectContext!.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil) as? [NSManagedObject] {
        if fetchResults.count != 0{

            var managedObject = fetchResults[0]
            managedObject.setValue(accessToken, forKey: "accessToken")

            context.save(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry about my language:(
If you don't understand my question, just say and I will explain more.

Comment: It would be better if you can attach your code snippet of what you have done.

Comment: you can search in google "edit in core data + swift" you will get links with demo in which you will get code to update/edit.

Comment: I tested them all but no one working on swift 3 :(

Comment: Provide your code of update which is not work.. so some one can observe that code or can give solution.